# Cyclic Redundancy Check How To?

Tags: c, crc

First off, I'm not sure if this is even the right place for it but I could really use any help.

So I am given an ASCII file that contains the string 
`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12345-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345a`and I am supposed to run a CRC-15 polynomial of (1010000001010011) of which its supposed to give me an answer of `1a6a`. I'm just trying to wrap my head around on how he got this. I've been using this site https://www.ghsi.de/CRC/, to check to see if I understand it correctly but I keep getting `346a`. My understanding is that each character from the string contains a specific hex value for it, thus on using the calculator I rewrite the message in hex with it looking something like `61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a...` then run the from there.

Anyone mind helping me with anything here?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment by any chance?  Also, what have you tried thus far?

Comment: @KenClement Yes. This is just the beginning steps of the program I have to make, I'm just trying to figure out how he got the `1a6a`. We've done paper assignments but with values much lower to give us an understanding of CRC. I know we have to take the message and translate it into binary, then do an XOR with the polynomial and the remainder would be our answer. Since the message is a too big for paper I don't really have room to try much.

Comment: That www.ghsi.de/CRC/ calculator works for me, see  (https://www.ghsi.de/CRC/index.php?Polynom=1010000001010011&Message=61+62+63+64+65+66+67+68+69+6A+6B+6C+6D+6E+6F+70+71+72+73+74+75+76+77+78+79+7A+31+32+33+34+35+41+42+43+44+45+46+47+48+49+4A+4B+4C+4D+4E+4F+50+51+52+53+54+55+56+57+58+59+5A+31+32+33+34+35+61+0A).  NB: a character of a string doesn't "contain" a hex value, rather the hex value is a way (ASCII) of encoding a char.

Comment: @agc we have to add the `-` character as well to the message and no need to include the `\n` character. But even so, your answer doesn't match with the answer he gave of `1a6a`. Makes me feel as if his answer is wrong.

Comment: @RiGid, sorry, just noticed that but you posted before I could delete my comment.  BTW, do we know the hyphen is needed?  Seeing it at the end of a continued line, I'd thought it  was a word wrap.

Comment: @agc Yeah hyphen is needed, it has to be 64 character.

Comment: @RiGid on retesting, I get '346a' also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108125/discussion-between-agc-and-rigid).

Comment: The CRC has not been sufficiently defined. A CRC is a bit-oriented calculation. Are the bits of each character fed in most-significant first or least-significant first? Should seven or eight bits be fed in per character? What is the initial value of the CRC register? Should the CRC register be exclusive-ored with a constant at the end? How should the CRC register be read out as an integer value (which end becomes the most significant bit of the integer)?

Comment: @agc yeah professor had the wrong answer haha

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework assignment, I'll give relevant suggestions but no code - that is the job of the student.

1. Process the string value a byte at a time and for each byte process the bits one at a time.  One can parse the bits from a byte string starting with 0x80 and right shifting up to and including 0x01.  This produces a mask that can be bit-wise ANDed with the current byte.  (an ?: operation or an if statement can be used to disambiguate the value into a 1 or a 0.
2. Simulate what a hardware circuit would do with that bit.  This can be done with simple bit-wise ANDs, XORs, shifts, etc.
3. It is quite possible to write a simple function that accepts as input the CRC state including the polynomial.

There are multiple ways to go about the calculation, this being only one of them.  I have a function of a few lines that performs this calculation as described but as I stated at the outset, the homework assignment is the job of the student.

Good luck to you.